# How to teach a computer to make deduction

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

File 1

```
| value11 value21 value31     
| value12 value22 value32
| value13 value23 value33  
| value14 value24 value34
| value15 value25 value35    
| value16 value26 value36
```

File 2

```
| value21     
| value22
| value23  
|
```

Let's say I have the two precedent files.

For a human being, it's easy to complete File 2 : it's the values from the second column of File 1.

Is there a way to teach the computer that kind of deduction ?

Comment: That would be the second column. Yes, you could "teach" the computer by defining rule sets. But will it ascertain this on its own? Possibly someday. Possibly now. Not by my understanding though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *the computer* only has to deduce which one of those columns was selected then your problem becomes a trivial check against every source column.

If the problem you presented was only an example and your actual question is the following

> Given two files with some more-or-less *obvious*<sup>1</sup> relationship can I teach *the computer* to deduce the relationship

The answer quickly becomes more **no** than yes. You might be able to teach this specific problem by tediously listing every thinkable relationship and have *the computer* check each one of them. But if you are looking for some kind of *strong* artificial intelligence that can handle arbitrary problems by itself just like humans then no, we don't have that.

That being said we have lots of less sophisticated AIs each designed to handle a very specific problem domain and they work pretty well.

1. *More or less obvious* to an human expert who might have an idea what to look for, that is

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you guessed well, my question concern a less obvious relationship between two files.